# Workaround with single point objects and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have a problem on a piece of homework where we have to create our own point class (which I have done) which I then used in creating 3 shape classes: Triangle, Rectangle and Circle. We then have to make each of these classes an extension of the Shape class but I am having trouble with one part.

I have an array of 3 predetermined point objects that would be used to make the points of a triangle. But the Shape class works with a single point object rather than an array. What would be a good workaround to make Shape accept a single point object but also an array of point objects?

Here is the Triangle class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

/**
 *
 * @author Henry
 */
public class Triangle extends Shape {

    private int sides = 3;
    private Point[] points;  //Error line here

    public Triangle(Point[] vertices) {
        super(3, vertices, Color.red);
        points = vertices; 
    }
```

Here is the shape class

```
public class Shape {
    private int sides;
    private Color colour;
    private Point coordinates;

    public Shape (int sides, Point p, Color c) {
        this.sides=sides;
        colour = c;
        coordinates = p;
    }
```

All the methods work its just one line of code in triangle which isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would a `Shape` have only one `Point`...in fact, why would it have any at all, wouldn't it be possible to make `Shape` `abstract`?

Comment: You're trying to call your `super` constructor with a `Point` array. Your `super` constructor takes a single `Point`..

Comment: `Shape` takes a single point in `Circle`(the center) and `Rectangle`(the top corner) where as in `Triangle` its a three point array. Which is why i need a workaround which lets `Shape` take a single `Point` object and an array. The spec for the homework requires `Shape` to take `Point` objects to work out the area/perimeter etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It is good practice not to call variables in every location different (p, coordinates, vertices...)

```
public class Shape {
    protected int sides;
    private Color color;
    protected Point[] coordinates;

    public Shape (int sides, Color color, Point... coordinates) {
        this.sides=sides;
        this.color = c;
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }
}


public class Triangle extends Shape {

    public Triangle(Point[] coordinates) {
        super(3, Color.red, coordinates);
    }
}
```